# Pandas replace substring from dict of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is sample Dataframe

```
data = {'A': ['hi UK','hi IN','hi US']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I wanted to update UK, IN values for A column from matching dict below

```
abs = {'U': 'UK -- extra', 'UK': 'test Kingdom', 'IN':'India'}
```

then I used [replace function (pandas.DataFrame.replace)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace(to_replace = abs, regex=True)
print(df)

                           A
0  hi test Kingdom -- extraK
1                   hi India
2  hi test Kingdom -- extraS
```

Its replacing U first by `UK -- extra` and again `UK` with `test kingdom` so final result is  `hi test Kingdom -- extraK` idially it should give test kingdom

The expected output is

```
                 A
0  hi test Kingdom
1         hi India
2            hi US
```

Am i missing any thing or is there anyway to achieve above result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think word boundary should help here for match `UK`, `US` and no `U`:

```
data = {'A': ['hi UK','hi IN','hi US']}

d = {'U': 'UK -- extra', 'UK': 'test Kingdom', 'IN':'India'}

d = {r'\b{}\b'.format(k):v for k, v in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['A'] = df['A'].replace(to_replace = d, regex=True)
print(df)
                 A
0  hi test Kingdom
1         hi India
2            hi US
```